# Disappearing comments?

Tags: support, comments

Yesterday (about 18 hours ago) I answered [this question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/61731/38714) and put some comments to my own answer. Today, I have revisited it and added three comments to someone else answers. Particularly to [this one](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/61732/38714) (reply to *lesto*'s comment), to [this one](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/61736/38714) (with a link to my reply to *lesto*'s comment) and to [this one](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/61754/38714).

Now, **all three of my comments are gone** and my activity tab shows nothing about them.

I tried to refresh page many times and see it through different browsers, to prevent any chances, that something "choked" on cache or sth. No effect. I'm pretty sure, that I wrote these comments, because I'm editing my own blog in the same time and I have copied contents of these comments to by post.

Can someone verify, what has happen and reply me, why my comments were removed? Since there is not trace about them in my user's activity tab, I think, I need a help from side of site administrator or anyone else with access to internal logs.

Answer (score 1):

The comments on other answers were removed as [non-constructive and off-topic](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/flagging). Comments maybe removed that do not:

> Try to improve the post it appears on, or which introduces a topic
>   unrelated to the question or answer.

That also includes comments that invite extended discussions or are difficult to follow, which seemed to be the case here as well.

The comments on your own answer were left since they were addressing the OP's question and comments.

Comment: I see. So... You say: "There is a problem with connection-lag" and I say: "You're wrong, file will be read from cache, there will be no connection at all". You disagree with me and you... remove my comment? Can you, please, explain, how do you find my comment not constructive or off-topic? Because, I clearly see, that someone with bigger moderation rights, than mine, simply removed an alternative answer, that he doesn't agree with. That is a 100% pure definition of censorship, are you aware of that?

Comment: Another example? Someone says: "Inline code is better for debugging". I say: "No, you're wrong. We're talking about production code. Nobody is debugging production code. Your argument is pointless". Again, would you care to explain, how do you find such comment not constructive or off-topic? This is a very young SE site. On Stack Overflow I saw hundreds of comments much more off-topic or not constructive, and they're battled with a reasonable discussion, not just removed. I can clearly see, that you're using moderation rights in a very not user-friendly way.

Comment: For your reference, I have copied contents of above comments and my question, to use them in discussion over what you have done, at Stack Exchange Meta. I'm getting the feeling, that you're going to remove them as well. I can clearly see, that you're removing way to much and that you misunderstood definition of something being not constructive or off-topic very much.

Comment: The comments were removed for the above reasons, not because I disagreed with you, or you with others.

Comment: Assuming, that I don't understand your opinion here, I asked you to further explain me, how do you find my comments not constructive, off topic or inviting extended discussion? I say, once again, that non of them fall into such definition, according to me. In my opinion, they just express an alternative vision and by no meaning are useless, off-topic or not constructive. Saying, that something is off-topic or not constructive is a strong accuse. Either support it with some arguments / explanation or bring the comments back. They're **not** off-topic or not constructive.

Comment: Well, one of your comments started with: `Se ma comment to lesto's comment, made to closetnoc's answer` _on someone else's answer_...and goes on to repeat the same information in your own answer, also repeated in the other comments too. I'm sorry, but I'm not going to argue point-by-point with you, as it seems you were inviting other users to do as well. It's the responsibility of moderators to remove noise like that which detracts from other helpful information.

Comment: The comment, you cited above, can be found repetitive. I can agree on that. Which doesn't change the fact, that linking to own comment in another comment is fine on other sites of SE. But, let's leave this behind. And what about my comment [to this answer](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/61731/is-inline-javascript-good-or-bad/61754#61754)? It was about "debug" argument. It was **second** argument in row (so: no too chatty, does not invite extended discussions) and it clearly pointed out, that answer is partially wrong (so: constructive and not off-topic). Yet you removed it.

Comment: And you have even removed the `+1` comment, made by someone else, that was above mine. And that existed for a longer time. Though all other sites agrees and even encourages comments, that explains upvotes and downvotes. You're clearly removing way to much on this site!

Comment: The +1 comment was actually my own. Please refer to my comments above regarding the rest.